# CodeBar component disappearing when sending to Printer

Tags: delphi, printing, reportbuilder

I'm trying to develop a report in Delphi XE4 and Report Builder 15.01 using CodeBar component.

When I print to screen the print is normal, but when I send that print to the printer, the codebar component disappear from the print, leaving just a blank space in its place.

I'm not changing its properties in runtime.

What could it be?

**Edit:**
The CodeBar component only disappear when the device is "Printer", if I change it to PDF for example, it prints correctly.

**Edit2:**
I have found another behavior: the Codebar doesn't disappear, it creates another codebar inside, with the same properties, but just visually. I could post images to make thing much clearer but i don't have anough rep points. lol.

**Edit3:**
I have tryed the version 14 and for my surprise the problem doesn't exist. I guess it's a bug from RB.

Comment: What settings are you using for the BarCode component and do you have an event in that fire when printing (OnBeforePrint etc)

Comment: @Re0sless I have tried changing all the properties, there is no exact config I'm using. This event happens even with the default properties, and I'm not using any event, neither in ppReport nor in the CodeBar component.

Comment: Have you tried printing to a different printer (preferably a different manufacturer)? I've had issues in the past with ReportBuilder where a report would print fine on every printer apart from a HP. It may well be driver related.

Comment: @Andy_D I tryed using a virtual PDF exporter (Win2PDF), virtual XPS exporter (default Windows 8) and a fisical HP Printer, all them had the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after changing the version to 14 the problem has been solved. Not only this problem but some others layout problems.